# Finding the volume bounded by two equations rotated around $y = 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

I need to find the volume of a solid generated by a rotating the area bounded by the equations about $y = 2$:

- $y = 1$
- $y = x^2$

I've graphed the functions, but I'm not sure how to setup an integral to find the volume.

Comment: What've you tried? Can you show us your integral?

Comment: @AndrewLi I am supposed to come up with the integral based on y=x^2, y=1 about y=2, but I have no clue on how to setup the integral based on those facts.

Comment: Did you draw up a graph?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, but I still haven't the slightest clue as to what to use as my radius' nor do I know what to use for my boundaries.

Comment: @AndrewLi So I would setup the integral from 0 to sqrt(2)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73697/discussion-between-sam-goodin-and-andrew-li).

Comment: I misunderstood your problem, I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: If you find this difficult, just shift everything vertically downward by $2$. Then it becomes the standard rotate about the $x$-axis sort of problem.

Answer (score -2):

Think of this as a washer problem, with the volume resembling a ring. The inner radius is bounded by $y = 1$ while the outer is bounded by $y = x^2$. Where they intersect, at $x^2 = 2$ or $x = \sqrt 2$ is your upper bound of integration.

Notice that the inner radius is $2 - 1$ because that's the difference between $y = 2$ and $y = 1$. The outer radius is $2-x^2$ accordingly. Thus:

$$\pi\int_0^{\sqrt2} (2 -1)^2 - \left(2-x^2\right)^2 dx$$

Depending on what your lower bound is (it could be $x = -\sqrt 2$), you can multiply accordingly via symmetry (by $2$).

Comment: How do $y=1$ and $y=x^2$ intersect when $x=\pm \sqrt2$?